# User agent strings purpose?

Tags: user-agent

What is the purpose of a browser's agent string? If it gives information about the browser that the user is accessing the website from but it can be spoofed; I see no reason for it.

Comment: What is the purpose of currency? People can spoof that and yet somehow we still find a use for it.

Comment: True and not so true. Unlike currency which can eventually be validated and/or rejected, a user agent string never reach a point of confirmation. As in we as developers can never know the true browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3):

> The "User-Agent" header field contains information about the user
> agent originating the request, which is often used by servers to help
> identify the scope of reported interoperability problems, to work
> around or tailor responses to avoid particular user agent
> limitations, and for analytics regarding browser or operating system
> use.

… and as far as spoofing is concerned:

> If a user
> agent masquerades as a different user agent, recipients can assume
> that the user intentionally desires to see responses tailored for
> that identified user agent, even if they might not work as well for
> the actual user agent being used.

Comment: Okay the second statement makes sense. I wished I had marked this answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

Because it gives information about the browser that the user is accessing the website from.

The site can use the user agent header to render different experiences.  For example, if the browser presents a user-agent string for an iPhone, the site may return a 302 redirect to the mobile UX.  If it presents a user-agent string for a very old browser, the site may return a redirect to a downlevel UX, e.g. one that doesn't require javascript, or one that doesn't require HTML5.

Sure, it can be spoofed; so can a lot of other stuff.  Not sure why you think that negates its use.  For non-malicious users it is very handy for tailoring the site.

Comment: It negates purpose because it's giving false statistical information.

Comment: A minority of bad actors lying in the UA doesn't render the entire dataset worthless.

Comment: I didn't mean anything on the intention of operability. Speaking statistically and functionally it has no true value if it is spoofed.

Comment: I don't know what "true value" means.  I'm an engineer and I stick to technical matters.  If you wish to state that something is unsuitable for fulfilling a specific requirement, would be happy to discuss.  Otherwise, perhaps you should seek out [this forum](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).